# Lead node fails with /tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/jars.data (Permission denied)

Tags: snappydata

SnappyData v.0-5

I am logged into Ubuntu as a non-root user, 'foo'.
SnappyData directory/install is owned by 'foo' user and 'foo' group.

I am starting ALL nodes (locator,lead,server) with a script here:

SNAPPY_HOME/sbin/snappy-start-all.sh

Locator starts.
Server starts.
Lead dies with this error.

> 16/07/21 23:12:26.883 UTC serverConnector INFO JobFileDAO:
>   rootDir is /tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data 16/07/21 23:12:26.888 UTC
>   serverConnector ERROR JobServer$: Unable to start Spark
>   JobServer:  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at spark.jobserver.JobServer$.start(JobServer.scala:69)     at
>   io.snappydata.impl.LeadImpl.startAddOnServices(LeadImpl.scala:283)    at
>   io.snappydata.impl.LeadImpl$.invokeLeadStartAddonService(LeadImpl.scala:360)
>     at
>   io.snappydata.ToolsCallbackImpl$.invokeLeadStartAddonService(ToolsCallbackImpl.scala:28)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$.invokeServices(SnappyContext.scala:1362)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$.initGlobalSnappyContext(SnappyContext.scala:1340)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext.(SnappyContext.scala:104)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext.(SnappyContext.scala:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$.newSnappyContext(SnappyContext.scala:1221)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SnappyContext$.apply(SnappyContext.scala:1249)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.SnappyTaskSchedulerImpl.postStartHook(SnappyTaskSchedulerImpl.scala:25)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:601)     at
>   io.snappydata.impl.LeadImpl.start(LeadImpl.scala:129)     at
>   io.snappydata.impl.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.scala:32)  at
>   io.snappydata.tools.LeaderLauncher.startServerVM(LeaderLauncher.scala:91)
>     at
>   com.pivotal.gemfirexd.tools.internal.GfxdServerLauncher.connect(GfxdServerLauncher.java:174)
>     at
>   com.gemstone.gemfire.internal.cache.CacheServerLauncher$AsyncServerLauncher.run(CacheServerLauncher.java:1003)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /tmp/spark-jobserver/filedao/data/jars.data (Permission denied)   at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)  at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)    at
>   spark.jobserver.io.JobFileDAO.init(JobFileDAO.scala:90)   at
>   spark.jobserver.io.JobFileDAO.(JobFileDAO.scala:30)     ... 22 more
>   16/07/21 23:12:26.891 UTC Distributed system shutdown hook
>   INFO snappystore: VM is exiting - shutting down distributed system

Do I need to be a different user to start the Lead node?  Use 'sudo'?  Configure a property to tell Spark to use a directory 'foo' has permission to?  Create this directory myself ahead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the current owner of /tmp/spark-jobserver is some other user. Check the permissions on that directory and delete it.

If multiple users will be running leads on the same machine, you can configure the job-server directories to be elsewhere like mentioned [here](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#context-configuration). The relevant properties can be found in [application.conf](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver/blob/master/job-server/src/main/resources/application.conf) source. This is probably more trouble than worth, so for now it will be easier to just ensure a single user starts the lead nodes on a machine.

We shall be fixing the default to be inside work/ directory in next release (SNAP-69).